# Cross-system file links

Tags: file-sharing, dropbox, filelink

We are using complex directory tree, shared via DropBox on Windows and Ubuntu.

Somewhere we need to refer files, placed in other folders (like `Invoice_5.doc` must be found under `Invoices` as well as under `Clients/SomeName`).

Before Ubuntu we were able to use .lnk files. But what is the best solution for now when we are using Ubuntu (Gnome) and Windows?

Answer (score 2):

It [appears](https://getsatisfaction.com/dropbox/topics/symlinks_symbolic_links_to_other_files_inside_dropbox_are_destroyed_on_change) that if you create a file and a symbolic link on computer A, on computer B dropbox just creates two separate copies of the file. Probably not what you want.

The closest equivalent to a `.lnk` file in Linux is a [desktop](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) file. An example link-type `.desktop` file is a text file containing:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Invoice_5.doc
Type=Link
URL=file:///home/username/Dropbox/Clients/SomeName/Invoice_5.doc
```

All of these fields are mandatory, and the URL must conform to the [file URL scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme), so only absolute paths are possible.

To automate creating such links, you'll need to look into adding a custom action to Nautilus.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create symbolic links?

```
ln -s Invoices/Invoice_5.doc Client/SomeName/
```

will create a symbolic link in the directory `Client/SomeName/` with the original remaining in `Invoices/`. Of course, you can do it with a Nautilus (right-click, "Make link").

However, I don't know DropBox and I do not know how DropBox treats symbolic links.